# openssl s_server mutual TLS

Tags: ssl, openssl

I can use the openssl s_server command to accept TLS sessions from clients, and to require mutual TLS - i.e. request client certificate - using a command such as: -

```
openssl s_server -accept 4433 -cert myCert.crt -key -myKey.pem -Verify 2 -CAfile myCA.crt
```

When I connect from a client, I can see from tracing that s_client sends a certificate request, correctly stipulating the certificate contained within myCA.crt. However it seems that s_server will accept *any* client certificate, regardless of whether it was signed by myCA.crt or not - i.e. it doesn't care which client cert is sent.

Does anyone know if this is expected behaviour, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: s_server and s_client usually only print out the status of the verification and don't stop on verification errors. If you want it differently check `-verify_return_error` option.

Comment: Thank you Steffen. Yes, that works for me - feel free to post as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

openssl s_server and s_client by default verify the peers certificate and show the verification status but don't stop on errors. If this is necessary use the `-verify_return_error` option.